# If I uninstall Minecraft Forge, will it also remove the mods I installed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I uninstall Minecraft Forge, will it also remove the mods I installed with the help of Forge or will it still be in my folder? And can I reinstall the Forge mod so I can play without any mods and have the new version of Minecraft? I have not yet got the game because I am gonna be doing a Minecraft roleplay but I sometimes want to play the game without any mods. I looked up how to disable mods but it doesn't answer the question I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you launch the forge client, you should be able to enable and disable mods. If you launch the regular Minecraft client, you will not be able to play your Forge mods at all. All you have to do is launch the default client for Minecraft, and not the Forge one.

Comment: Actually, there is a way to play with Forge mods on the standard client, Ive been doing it for years.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the Forge client shouldn't remove any mods that you installed, the Forge client is just a way to access those mods, it doesn't actually contain the mods in the client. The mods you install are stored in a separate file then the client. If you want to play without mods then get the standard Minecraft client or Badlion client, either one should work.

Answer (score 1):

When you install forge, it goes straight into the versions folder. since the mods are in the mods folder, forge has nothing to do with it. When forge is deleted, it will keep the installed mods in the folder.